# Wrong use of switch statement : the program takes the value it's not supposed to accept

Tags: c, switch-statement

That is a beginner question to understand where I might be wrong using the switch statement. 
The task is as follows: 
*Write a program that accepts two integer values typed in by the user. Display the
result of dividing the first integer by the second, to three-decimal-place accuracy.
Remember to have the program check for division by zero.*

To test whether the second operand is a 0, I have used switch statement (I know I could have done that with if...else). However, the program will still accept 0 as the operand I am unsure why this happens. If it tries to calculate the division by 0, the program will simply fail. Could you please give me a hint as to where I might be wrong? My code is below:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main (void)

  {
         int a, b;


   printf ("Type two integer values: ");
   scanf ("%i %i", &a, &b);

   switch (a/b)
   {

   case 'b == 0':
        printf ("\n The divisor can't be 0.\n");

   break;

   default:
           printf ("The result of dividing %i by %i is %.3f\n", a, b,(float) a / b);

   break;
  }
  return 0;

  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `'b == 0'` should be `b == 0;` shouldn't it? I'm not sure since I have never used a switch statement. But it still doesn't look like valid C to me.

Comment: Edited title to stop blaming the decades old programming language.

Comment: and this switch(a/b) does not make any sense there ...

Comment: Okay honestly this code doesn't make any sense at all...  voting to close as narq, please read C books.

Comment: Calling BS on this one. Please read some basic book on C language first.

Comment: you should compile with warnings options switched on

Comment: @djechlin did you find the problem?

Comment: @KeithMiller I've found lots of problems.

Comment: @djechlin whoops I thought you were OP because I misread the asker and edit area. I've been sitting at this office for too long :P

Comment: @djechlin Reading books now, just couldn't get why it was not working. I indicated in my question that was an easy one (beginner level). If that is too simple to be asked here, I apologize.

Comment: @wondersz1 simple is okay, however it was clear to me that you did not understand the syntax of a switch statement, and I am guessing you changed the text in the switch and case statements until it compiled, then became confused by the behavior. Proper instinct here is to re-read a chapter or a tutorial on the programming construct in question, and if you are still confused you will probably have a more specific question at that point (e.g. "Why does 'a == b' mess up this switch statement?), and informed, specific questions are more appropriate for SO.

Comment: @djechlin That was something I did before posting the question. But the program would still accept 0 as an operand. The only thing i want to ask you personally: you didn't provide any input or help with this question besides down-voting it. What was your motivation to leave comments on this one? You knew the answer but rather preferred to leave irrelevant comments and down-voting valid answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 switch (b)
   {
   case 0:
        printf ("\n The divisor can't be 0.\n");

   break;
   default:
           printf ("The result of dividing %i by %i is %.3f\n", a, b,(float) a / b);
   break;
  }
```

Also note, the expressions following `case` must be constants such as:

```
case 0:
case 1:
case 'a':
case 'b':
```

etc

There.. that should fix it.

Comment: the second break is unnecessairy and he should better use a function for this but this answer is ok

Comment: @wondersz1 that's cool

Comment: Downvoting for posting complete code when it's clear the user does not understand the mechanisms s/he is inquiring about.

Comment: @djechlin see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16236/when-should-correct-answers-get-downvoted

Comment: @Aniket Agree. That was an absolutely correct and excellent answer. No reason at all to down-vote it.

Comment: IMO it's a counterproductive answer - user is as confused re. switch statements and will probably post a similar question here before too long because the copy/paste job worked. Less programming knowledge happened as a result of this code being posted, and this is a more valid metric for the quality of an SO answer than number of compilable lines of code that make it into homework submissions. That is the reason for my downvote.

Comment: @djechlin the OP may learn from this. We cannot judge that can we?

Comment: @Aniket - of course we can judge that, we do whenever we post any answer or vote on any answer or question.  Usually a correct answer is all it takes to be helpful; this is not one of those times and we should apply judiciousness to when "correct" and "helpful" diverge.

Comment: @djechlin Still, that was a correct answer to the question. And I thank Aniket for the help. Your comments on this were not as useful as his/her answer: you only advised the asker to read more books which i am doing now and suggested that this question be closed as this is too simple (meta allows for beginner-type questions to be asked here). Please, consider your input before down-voting.

Comment: @wondersz1 just so djechlin knows this wasn't that bad an answer, what did you understand from the answer I posted?

Comment: @Aniket I understood I was using the switch statement in the wrong way. I should have been precise as regards the operand that i am checking with switch statement. I also realized I was using wrong syntax (no quotes needed). Plus to that I shouldn't have put an expression after the case clause, a value of 0 would have sufficed. I think that was a good answer.

Comment: See? People learn gradually - even by looking at wrong and correct programs. That is why SO was built, for comparing **your** techniques with **correct** techniques, and inadvertently, help yourself.

Comment: Sigh...  fair.  I will say that I do stand by my judgment call that in most cases these are counterproductive but it is good to hear that the OP digested this solution instead of copying/pasting it, which was absolutely my instinct. DV is locked in now though.

Comment: @djechlin I've edited the answer, and perhaps, the DV should be unlocked now

Answer (score 0):

Case labels cannot be conditional expressions; they must be constant integer values.

In this case, you want to write:

```
switch (b) {
case 0:
    /* stuff goes here */
    break;
}
```

However, a switch statement is very weird here. An if statement would be more appropriate.

Comment: that's not a conditional statement, its compiler dependent literal

Comment: @David Morris Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the switch statement to
      switch (b)

Comment: -1 this answer is useless (fact is already mentionned) and unnecessairy as it is already solved